# How to access resource strings from ListFragment

Tags: android

I am new to Android development so maybe I am missing something pretty simple, but I can't seem to access the string resources found in `res/values/strings.xml` from a `ListFragment` that was created by the `MasterDetailFlow` template in ADT.

It looks like a different resource file is loaded because when I type `R.string.`, auto-complete suggests a whole bunch of string I didn't create. (e.g. cancel, cut, paste, emptyPhoneNumber)

Where are these string resources coming from and how do I access my own string resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the bad import to android.R and add your own project's R.

Comment: Thanks! That was easy. So importing adroid.R loads some default/common string resources and overrides my resources I take it?

Comment: Not so much overrides, but if your source file has an import for `android.R` and it sees a reference to `R` in your code, it's going to look for something in your imports that matches it, which in your case, was `android.R`.

Comment: Got it. I didn't see that `R` is a static class that is automatically generated. I was assuming it was a class variable of Activity/Fragment. It all makes sense now.